# Maximum search method in several columns and unification of the result within a single column with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following Dataset :

```
+----+-----+--------+-----+--------+
|  id|date1|address1|date2|address2|
+----+-----+--------+-----+--------+
|   1| 2019|   Paris| 2018|  Madrid|
|   2| 2020|New York| 2002|  Geneva|
|   3| 1998|  London| 2005|   Tokyo|
|   4| 2005|  Sydney| 2013|  Berlin|
+----+-----+-------+------+--------+
```

I try to obtain the most recent date and the corresponding address of each `id` in two other columns. The desired result is :

```
+----+-----+--------+-----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  id|date1|address1|date2|address2|date_max|address_max|
+----+-----+--------+-----+--------+--------+-----------+
|   1| 2019|   Paris| 2018|  Madrid|    2019|      Paris|
|   2| 2020|New York| 2002|  Geneva|    2020|   New York| 
|   3| 1998|  London| 2005|   Tokyo|    2005|      Tokyo|
|   4| 2005|  Sydney| 2013|  Berlin|    2013|     Berlin|
+----+-----+-------+------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Any ideas to make this in a very efficient way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `CASE WHEN` to pick the more recent date/address:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val date_max = when(col("date1") > col("date2"), col("date1")).otherwise(col("date2")).alias("date_max")
val address_max = when(col("date1") > col("date2"), col("address1")).otherwise(col("address2")).alias("address_max")

df = df.select("*", date_max, address_max)
```

If you want a more scalable option with many columns:

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "all_date",
    array(df.columns.filter(_.contains("date")).map(col): _*)
).withColumn(
    "all_address",
    array(df.columns.filter(_.contains("address")).map(col): _*)
).withColumn(
    "date_max",
    array_max($"all_date")
).withColumn(
    "address_max",
    element_at($"all_address",
        (array_position($"all_date", array_max($"all_date"))).cast("int")
    )
).drop("all_date", "all_address")

df2.show
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+----------+
| id|date1|address1|date2|address2|datemax|addressmax|
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+----------+
|  1| 2019|   Paris| 2018|  Madrid|   2019|     Paris|
|  2| 2020| NewYork| 2002|  Geneva|   2020|   NewYork|
|  3| 1998|  London| 2005|   Tokyo|   2005|     Tokyo|
|  4| 2005|  Sydney| 2013|  Berlin|   2013|    Berlin|
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: In my case, I have about fifteen date and address columns to compare. How I can use the ```CASE WHEN``` function with so many columns ?

Comment: @Mamaf I have updated my answer for many columns